# Why can't I see my debug errors in Chrome's Sources tab

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I am using web dev tools in Chrome to debug some JavaScript. The question is not about code, but what the browser is doing.

In the below JavaScript, I've added some code to create an exception. The mouse pointer is hovering over the red circle with the white arrow and the pop up is displayed. The issue is, as you can see, it appears as if there is no information.

If I open the Console tab, the error message is shown as expected.

I can't tell if this tab just doesn't have the information or if the message box needs to be expanded. How do I show the error message in the Sources tab when I hover over the error?

[image]